# Gaussian random variable sum dependent on different random variable

Tags: probability

> Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ be a series of i.i.d random variables, with a distribution of $X_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$.  Let us define $S_N=\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i$.
> On the first part, it states that $N\geq0$ is a deterministic constant, and asks to find the characteristic function os $S_N$.

I found it to be :
$$\phi_{S_N}(\omega)=e^{-\frac{N}{2}\omega^2\sigma^2}$$
On the second part it says:

> N is a discrete random variable that gets the values of 1 and 2 in an equal probability, meaning
> $$\Bbb P(N=1)=\Bbb P(N=2)=0.5$$
> Also, N is independent of $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$. Find the characteristic function of $S_N$.

I don't know how to relate to the fact that the upper bound is a random variable itself. How do I solve this?

Comment: If $N$ and  $X_i$ are independent, you can just divide the cases of $N$ and calculate.

Comment: I forgot to add the fact that they are indeed independent. And after I divide the cases, what is the final outcome of the characteristic function?

Comment: It would be some thing like following: $$ \dfrac{1}{2} \left[ \phi_{S_1}(\omega)+\phi_{S_2}(\omega)  \right] $$

Comment: Great, thank you!